# How to save canvas drawings to Assets folder?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

In swift and swiftUI, I am developing drawing canvas image and trying to save image to "Assets" folder.

How to save the drawing in Canvas (or path and stroke drawings) to "Assets" folder or snapshot the frame of the drawings to "photo"?

Comment: You cannot save to Assets in run-time because it is in main app bundle which is read-only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. First step should always be searching. Head over to google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift ios save files`